# Gem Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, paperclip

I'm trying to upload .pdf and .doc with paperclip.

```
Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/86/5tdcyh5171j6twqqkt49tq040000gn/T/d031fe0d3003c25aa6a9d1525403031a20140707-7537-6y9s83.pdf'
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/86/5tdcyh5171j6twqqkt49tq040000gn/T/d031fe0d3003c25aa6a9d1525403031a20140707-7537-1ru9fns.pdf[0]' 2>/dev/null
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError>
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/86/5tdcyh5171j6twqqkt49tq040000gn/T/d031fe0d3003c25aa6a9d1525403031a20140707-7537-1ru9fns.pdf[0]' 2>/dev/null
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError>
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/86/5tdcyh5171j6twqqkt49tq040000gn/T/d031fe0d3003c25aa6a9d1525403031a20140707-7537-1b7261f.pdf'
   (0.2ms)  rollback transaction
```

Comment: Can you post your model?

Comment: Paperclip is trying to use imagemagick to resize the PDF into one of your defined styles. Remove the :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "345x215#" } part and it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resizing images i.e. `:styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "345x215#" }` requires [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org). Installing imagemagick should resolve the issue.

```
has_attached_file :media,
    :styles => {
      :medium => "300x300>",
      :thumb => "345x215#",
      :pdf_thumbnail => ["", :jpg]
    },
    :default_url => ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path('branch-default.jpg')

validates :media, :attachment_content_type => { :content_type => ['image/png', 'image/jpg', 'application/pdf', 'application/msword', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document']}
```

Also, specifying `pdf_thumbnail` for pdf uploads as it will generate a thumbnail image although I think this feature requires GhostScript: Here is an excerpt from the paperclip github page:

> If you are dealing with pdf uploads or running the test suite, you'll also need GhostScript to be installed.

Another useful link for other content type thumbnails:

[Custom thumbnails for file types with Paperclip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209179/custom-thumbnails-for-file-types-with-paperclip)